# Logstash Offline Plugin SocketError

Tags: logstash

I try to build and install a logstash plugin, so I run `bin/logstash-plugin prepare-offline-pack logstash-filter-http`.

When I run `bin/logstash-plugin install logstash-offline-plugins-7.7.0.zip` in an offline in environment I always get the message: `enterUnable to download data from https://rubygems.org - SocketError: Failed to open TCP connection to rubygems.org:443 (initialize: name or service not known) (https://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz) code here`, but it should not download anything.

Comment: Have you tried as the example in the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/offline-plugins.html#installing-offline-packs), with `logstash-plugin install file://logstash-offline-plugins-7.7.0.zip` ?

Comment: thanks, that's it, I misst `file://`